# How to change height of DIV based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="subpageHeaderImageSection">
    <div id="subpageHeaderLeft">
        <span id="holdImageP"></span>
            <!--[if lte IE 10]><img id="igm" src="theImages/subpageHeaderImageP.png" /><![endif]-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Which displays an image on my page as a header. The issue I am having is when the browser is stretched the width changes but not the height.

Here is an example of a normal display monitor which displays the image just fine inside the DIV:

[image]

But if I stretch the browser, the image expands in width but not in height:

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
#subpageHeaderImageSection {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
#subpageHeaderLeft {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#holdImageP {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../theImages/subpageHeaderImageP.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Can I use JQuery or even CSS to stretch the height based on the width of the DIV so the image doesn't look stretched on some screen?

Comment: Your image is not expanding in height because you have an explicit height of 400px set for #subpageHeaderImageSection.

Comment: browsers will automatically resize images based on width values you provide - don't set the height or it will stretch it to the container size - this is what is causing your issue most likely

Comment: For a normal screen resolution, I want it at 400px height but as the user stretches the browser I want the height to change proportionally... If I don't set the height of the DIV how will it know how much to show in the webpage?

Comment: Use `background-size: cover`. It will adjust the image to make sure the image covers the div and keeps the aspect ratio. `100% 100%` makes both width and height 100% of the container.

Comment: `background-size: cover` in the main DIV?

Comment: No, the span that's holding the image.

Comment: That's what I am using if not IE but what about if it's IE 8?

Comment: It's an inline image then right? You can set `height: 100%; width: auto;` and it should expand to fill the container height-wise. You may need to change the image size at certain breakpoints with media-queries.

Comment: I was going to use image queries but I don't know exactly when the image gets distorted. I was hoping to start at the normal screen which looks fine and expand from there...

Comment: You may want to specify that your issue is in IE8 in your question. I'd recommend either making it so the site doesn't change sizes in IE8 with an IE8 and below stylesheet, or playing with the percentages. As someone else said, having a set height on the containing div is going to make things more difficult. Maybe try using `min-height: 400px;`

Comment: The issue with all browser. I mentioned IE8 is because of the commented out image in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you set a specific height on an image it will always stay that height regardless of browser resize
2. When you set a specific height on a "container" or an element surrounding your image, your image will be constricted to that containers dimensions.(generally speaking)

You will need to remove your `height: 400px` if you wish for the image to resize.

Note: Your image will only 'grow' to its natural size. So if you have an image that is 200px high and 200px wide thats as big as it will get(without altering picture).

Also... If you must have at LEAST 400px height on your image - try using

```
image{
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

This is basically just setting your image so that the very smallest height that it can be is 400px;

If you want your image to grow dynamically with browser resize there are several ways to accomplish that. Check out this tutorial
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I changed `height: 400px;` to `min-height: 400px` and nothing is happening. The original size of the image is 1500X600.

Comment: I had an issue with the image proportion and hence causing the stretch and collaboratively used your min-height and max-height and it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.. Glad you got it working.. The min-height is the MINIMUM height the image can be and max-height is the MAXIMUM height and image can be... This also applies to min-width and max-width